# Permission Denied - Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, installation, oracle12c

Installing Oracle 12c on Ubuntu I got `permission denied` when I executed the line:

```
/tmp/database/runInstaller
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ubuntu** is not certified OS for Oracle database installation. Run an OS that is certified by Oracle to support their products.

You could rather use **VirtualBox** and **Oracle Linux** to setup the Oracle database. It comes free for personal learning purpose.

Download Oracle Linux [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/default-150441.html).

[**Here**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-6) is a step-by-step installation guide by Tim Hall.

Comment: Where do I get the Oracle Linux?

Comment: @uikrosoft Updated my answer, see the link to download Oracle Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Check permission of .oui :

chmod 777 -r /tmp/database/

Even Ubuntu is not certified for Oracle Database installation, but it's possible to setup Oracle on this on. Not certified means that Oracle hadn't done tests and don't provide support on this plateform.

Comment: It looks like trying to hunt for a fly using a laser gun. It could workaround the problem, but certainly it is not a proper solution.